# Perl add <a></a> around words within an HTML/XML tag

Tags: html, xml, perl, text-processing

I have a file formatted like this one:

```
Eye color
<p class="ul">Eye color, color</p> <p class="ul1">blue, cornflower blue, steely blue</p> <p class="ul1">velvet brown</p> <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">
</>
weasel
<p class="ul">weasel</p> <p class="ul1">musteline</p> <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">
</>
```

Each word within the `<p class="ul1">` separated by `,`should be wrapped in an `<a>` tag, like this:

```
Eye color
<p class="ul">Eye color, color</p> <p class="ul1"><a href="entry://blue">blue</a>, <a href="entry://cornflower blue">cornflower blue</a>, <a href="entry://steely blue">steely blue</a></p> <p class="ul1"><a href="entry://velvet brown">velvet brown</a></p> <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">
</>
weasel
<p class="ul">weasel</p> <p class="ul1"><a href="entry://musteline">musteline</a></p> <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">
</>
```

> There could be one or several words within the `<p class="ul1">` tag.

Is this possible in `Perl` one-liner?

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you think it's more important to do it in one line of code than to make the code correct, robust, readable, and performant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse the file using a module and iterate over the elements you need (`<p>` of class `ul1`). Extract those comma-separated phrases from each and wrap links around them; then replace the element with that new content. Write the changed tree out in the end.

Using [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/CJM/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm) (with its workhorse [HTML::Element](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/CJM/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/Element.pm))

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use HTML::Entities;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file($file);

foreach my $elem ($tree->look_down(_tag => "p", class => "ul1")) {   
    my @new_content;
    for ($elem->content_list) { 
        my @w = split /\s*,\s*/; 
        my $wrapped = join ", ", 
            map { qq(<a href="entry://$_">).$_.q(</a>) } @w; 
        push @new_content, $wrapped;
    }
    $elem->delete_content;
    $elem->push_content( @new_content );
}; 

say decode_entities $tree->as_HTML;
```

In your case an element (`$elem`) will have one item in the `content_list` so you don't have to collect modified content into an array (`@new_content`) but can process that one piece only, what simplifies the code.  Working with a list as above doesn't hurt of course.

I redirect the output of this program to an `.html` file.  The generated file is qouite frugal on newlines. If pretty HTML matters make a pass with a tool like [HTML::Tidy](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Tidy) or [HTML::PrettyPrinter](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::PrettyPrinter).

In a one-liner?  Nah, it's too much. And please don't use regex as there's trouble down the road; it needs close work to get it right, is easy to end up buggy, is sensitive to smallest details, and brittle for even slightest changes in input. And that's when it *can* do the job. There are reasons for libraries.

Another good tool for this job is [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM). For example

```
use Mojo::DOM;
use Path::Tiny;  # only to read the file into a string easily

my $html = path($file)->slurp;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);

foreach my $elem ($dom->find('p.ul1')->each) {
    my @w = split /,/, $elem->text;
    my $new = join ', ',
        map { qq(<a href="entry://$_">).$_.q(</a>) } @w;
    $elem->replace( $new );
}

say $dom;
```

Produces the same HTML as above (just nicer, and note no need to deal with entities).

Newer module versions provide [new_tag](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#new_tag) method with which the additional link above is made as

```
my $new = join ', ', 
   map { $e->new_tag('a', 'href' => "entry://$_", $_) } @w;
```

what takes care of some subtle needs (HTML escaping for one). The main docs *don't say* when this method was added, see [changelog](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Mojolicious) (May 2018, so supposedly in v5.28; it works with my 5.29.2).

I padded the shown sample to this file for testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  <title>Eye color</title> <body>
<p class="ul">Eye color, color</p> 
<p class="ul1">blue, cornflower blue, steely blue</p> 
<p class="ul1">velvet brown</p> <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css"></>
weasel
<p class="ul">weasel</p> 
<p class="ul1">musteline</p> <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css"></>
</body> </html>
```

---

**Update**    It's been clarified that the given markup snippet isn't merely a fragment of a presumably full HTML document but that it is a file (as stated) that stands as shown, as a custom format using HTML; apart from the required changes the rest of it need be preserved.

A particularly unpleasant detail proves to be the `</>` part; each of `HTML::TreeBuilder`, `Mojo::DOM`, and `XML::LibXML`<sup>†</sup> discards it while parsing. I couldn't find a way to make them keep that piece.

It was [Marpa::HTML](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/JKEGL/Marpa-HTML-0.112000/lib/Marpa/HTML.pm) that processed the whole fragment as required, changing what was asked while leaving alone the rest of it.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Path::Tiny;

use Marpa::HTML qw(html);

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";
my $html = path($file)->slurp;

my $marpa = Marpa::HTML::html( 
    \$html,
    {
        'p.ul1' => sub {
            return join ', ', 
                map { qq(<a href="entry://$_">).$_.q(</a>) } 
                split /\s*,\s*/, Marpa::HTML::contents();
        },
    }
);  

say $$marpa;
```

The processing of the `<p>` tags of class `ul1` is the same as before: split the content on comma and wrap each piece into an `<a>` tag, then join them back with `,`

This prints (with added line-breaks and indentation for readability)

```
Eye color
<p class="ul">Eye color, color</p> 
<a href="entry://blue">blue</a>, 
    <a href="entry://cornflower blue">cornflower blue</a>, 
    <a href="entry://steely blue">steely blue</a> 
    <a href="entry://velvet brown">velvet brown</a> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">
</>
weasel
<p class="ul">weasel</p> <a href="entry://musteline">musteline</a> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">
</>
```

It is the overall approach of this module that is suited for a task like this

> `Marpa::HTML` is an extremely liberal HTML parser. `Marpa::HTML` does not reject any documents, no mater how poorly they fit the HTML standards.

Here it processed a custom piece of HTML-like markup, leaving things like `</>` in place.

---

<sup>†</sup> 
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56800341/4653379) for an example of very permissive processing of HTML with `XML::LibXML`

Comment: The new-ish [new_tag](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#new_tag) method might make generating the `<a>` tag even nicer with Mojo::DOM. In the current code, the string needs to be HTML-escaped when put into the raw HTML (both times).

Comment: @Grinnz Yeah, saw that. Thank you for the comment, I added it.  It is "funny" though that the docs don't say when this was introduced. Do they expect the user to install Perls one after another to find this out?  Go figure. (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: @zdim The [changelog](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Mojolicious) is pretty easy to search through. Listing when everything in Mojolicious was introduced would be quite the endeavor, the distribution strives to be consistent in all documentation. Not that I think it's a bad idea. (Also it has nothing to do with Perl version)

Comment: Can I make it keep the `</>` tag in the output file? because it's after all part of the source file. I'm using the `MOJO::DOM` approach.

Comment: @jonah_w Oh, I see that Mojo::DOM dropped that `</>`.  That doesn't add anything to the document (It's not a valid tag I think?) -- what does it do?  There may be a way to keep it.

Comment: @jonah_w No, Mojo::DOM does not preserve invalid HTML.

Comment: @Grinnz "_changelog is pretty easy to search through._" --- fair enough, added a comment, thank you.  However, it should be mentioned; it's no overhead in any sense since docs _need be_ adjusted when feature-set changes. (For example, this was introduced as experimental -- i'd expect docs to tell me _that_.  Then it was made stable.  Need to know these things without searching.)

Comment: @zdim I don't follow. None of these things are the case in the current version; you are viewing the current version's docs. You should either update to that version of Mojolicious, or look at the docs for the version you're using.

Comment: @zdim @Grinnz I think it's a special type of `html` source document made for `mdx` e-dictionary format. The `</>` is to distinguish each headword entry of that dictionary.

Comment: @Grinnz Well, sure. But I think it's common that people just fire up the browser and look up (thus the current) docs; I don't see why it would be hard to add a note once a documentation entry is added/changed.  It'd be just nice to have that.  But yes, you are right I guess -- it's not required.

Comment: @zdim `$e->replace( $new );` will delete the `<p class="ul1">` tag, I just looked up the document and changed it to `$elem->content( $new );` This keeps the `<p>` tag. Should it be `$elem`? I can't find a `$e` definition.

Comment: @jonah_w Interesting. So is the HTML fragment you show a part of a full HTML document (like what I show at the end), or is that fragment the whole thing to use (outside of any `<body>` etc) ?  I'm sorry, I don' tknow what that `mdx` e-dictionary format means.

Comment: @jonah_w Ah, good point!  Yes, it should be `$elem` -- it's an editing error. Fixing...

Comment: @zdim Yes, it's the whole thing to use. There's no `<body>` or `<html>` tag in it. After building the source html using a special build tool, an `mdx` file is created for use in some dictionary app, like GoldenDict.

Comment: @jonah_w Thank you for clarifications.  Will look into how to keep that `</>`, and will  adjust the answer anyway (to use given HTML fragment and not a full document from file).

Comment: Unfortunately if keeping the `</>` is a requirement, Mojo::DOM will not be sufficient for this job - it's designed for HTML, not custom formats that work sort of like HTML.

Comment: @jonah_w Yes, this changes things; I'll look into it. In the meanwhile, perhaps you can try with the approach from [this recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56800341/4653379), using `XML::LibXML` to parse HTML in a very permissive mode; it tolerates (and works with!) any semantic "tags" (`<>` things).  Content in XML can be changed/replaced for example like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41051651/4653379). (There is also a `Marpa` based approach given in the first link.)

Comment: @jonah_w That `</>` is particularly tricky for parsers: they all drop it (TreeBuilder, Mojo, XML) and I don't see how to make them keep it.  (Don't  even know how to call that in HTML lingo.) Once that's lost other questions are moot.  However, the `Marpa::HTML` one kept it (in the first link from the above comment) and I'll look tomorrow into that.  Otherwise it would actually come down to the (@#$%^) regex.

Comment: I've just tried the methods mentioned in the two posts. `LibXML` can't seem to support nodes without a start tag `<`.  And I can't get `Marpa::HTML` to first print the `<p>` info. p.s. I changed the `'key' => sub {` to `'p' => sub {`, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Seems like I did something wrong with the `Marpa::HTML`. After fixing it, It now displays the `<p>` info. will look into Marpa more.

Comment: @jonah_w Added (to the end) a way to do this exactly as needed using `Marpa::HTML`

Comment: @zdim This is so cool. I love this solution. I don't know if `Marpa::HTML` has a way of saving the changed content to a new file. For now I'm using `open my $out, '>', 'out.txt';
    print {$out} $$marpa;` Working great. Thanks @zdim

Comment: @jonah_w  Great, glad you like it :).  It's a super useful tool since it's so flexible. I don't think it can save, haven't seen anything similar to that.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
perl -0777 -MWeb::Query=wq -lne'
    my $w = wq $_; my $sep = ", ";
    $w->filter("p.ul1")->each(sub {
        my (undef, $e) = @_;
        $e->html(join $sep, map {
            qq(<a href="entry://$_">$_</a>)
        } split $sep, $e->text);
    });
    print $w->as_html;
'
```

Answer (score -1):

One-liner:

```
cat text | perl -pE 's{<p class="ul1">\K.*?(?=<\/p>)}{ join ", ", map {qq|<a href="entry://$_">$_</a>|} split /, */, $& }eg'
```

Comment: I'm using this: `perl -pE'/<p class="ul1">\K[\s\S]*?(?=<\/p>)/; @words=split /\s*, */, $&; $new_string=join ", ", map {qq|<a href="entry://$_">$_</a>|} @words; $_ =~ s/$&/$new_string/g; ' a.txt > b.txt ` But when there's brackets in the `<p class="ul1">` tag, it will not be matched. Is there some way around this except for using `s{}{}` directly. Your answer works good.

Comment: Can you provide example of such input data? One-liners is for throwaway solutions, and if task is rather complex, better write standalone script

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/mmtyNB/6 The `apart` entry has a `()` in the `<p>` tag as you can see.

Comment: Matched as `<a href="entry://(disconnected)">(disconnected)</a>`

Comment: I'm on macOS, in my trying, it didn't mark anything… don't know why.

Comment: I posted a new question regarding this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57097625/1118630