# Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE when replace a word wrapped in half ()

Tags: regex, perl

This one file contains one line of text:

```
<p>detached, (disconnected, unfastened</p>
```

I need the three words separated by `,` to be wrapped in `<a></a>`tags, like this:

```
<p><a href="entry://detached">detached</a>, <a href="entry://(disconnected">(disconnected</a>, <a href="entry://unfastened">unfastened</a></p>
```

When I run

```
perl -pE'/<p>\K.*?(?=<\/p>)/; @words=split(/, /, $&); $new_string=join ", ", map {qq|<a href="entry://$_">$_</a>|} @words; $_=~s/$&/$new_string/g;' a.txt
```

It gives the following error:

> Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE …

This one does work though:

```
perl -pE's{<p>\K.*?(?=<\/p>)}{join ", ", map {qq|<a href="entry://$_">$_</a>|} split(/, /, $&)}eg' a.txt
```

I don't know why, because basically behind them is the same idea. How does the first one not work as expected?

> I'm on macOS Catalina with Perl v5.28.1 if this matters.

Comment: Context: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57067500

Comment: `s/$&/$new_string/g` : You may need to quote the content of `$&`, i.e. `s/\Q$&\E/$new_string/g`, see [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for more information

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland  That works so well. :) wow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Håkon; the final substitution is interpreting the parenthesis that's in this input stream, and not finding a match to it. Can you not just print/emit your $new_string?

Comment: Indeed, the $new_string is all right. I guess I just got too confused… Thanks @Harlan for the explanation. `regex` is such… though I love it.:)

Comment: Agreed; regex is a bear sometimes, but amazingly useful after the learning curve.  And Perl's implementation of regex is really fantastic.