# Perl nested if statement

Tags: perl

I have this perl codes which basically read every line to find certain pattern. Against that pattern specified by the first `if` statement, I need to extract some substring from that pattern, hence the second `if` statement. Looking at the output, I find the result is not quite right, some get wrong binding between result from the two `if`s. Is is true that second `if` is reading from the same line as the first `if`? If not, how to read the same line for the second `if`?

```
open(DICT, "<", $file)
or die "Cannot open '$file': $!";
my %h;
while (<DICT>) {
    if (/(<p class="calibre_\d+">\s*?\d+\.\s*?(?:(?!<p).)*<\/p>)/) {
        my $entry = $1;
        
        if (/<p class="calibre_\d+">\s*?\d+\.\s*?\K([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\-_\s'’，“”=…\)()]+[a-zA-Z'\-’])/) {
            my $hw = $1;
            $h{$entry} = $hw;
        }
    }
    END{
        while (my ($k, $v) = each %h) {
            print qq{$v\n$k\n</>\n}
        }
    }
}
```

The source text file is like this:

```
A
<div class="notes"><p class="calibre_2">  注：</p><p class="calibre_2">  1.abc    字母</p>
</>
```

The result is expected like this:

```
abc
<p class="calibre_2">  1.abc    字母</p>
</>
```

That is, for all tags `<p class="calibre_\d+">`, if there's an English word within the tag that's behind the pattern `\d\.`, then extract it, link it with the corresponding tag where the word is located.

> Update:I just realized that if I separate all `<p class="calibre_\d+">` tags in different lines, this problem would be gone. Initially, all `<p class="calibre_\d+">` are in the same line for one word entry.
>
> So the new question should be: If those tags are in the same line, how to handle them individually?

Comment: Please, provide sample input and expected output so we can experiment with them. Also, using characters like `“”…` requires `use utf8;`.

Comment: Having an `END` block in the `while` loop is an interesting approach. What did you think it would do?

Comment: @DaveCross Indeed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @choroba I have updated the question. I just realized that if I separate all `<p class="calibre_\d+">` tags in different lines, this problem would be gone. Initially, all `<p class="calibre_\d+">` is in the same line for one word entry.

Comment: This looks like HTML. Why not just use an HTML parser?

Comment: When the structure is easy enough, I tend to use regex directly. But you're right, it should be bettering off using a parser, considering it's so easy to go wrong using regex for html file.

Comment: The second `if` sees the same line, yes. When you don't specify a variable, regular expressions apply to `$_`.

Comment: @joanis What if the `<p class="calibre_\d+">` tags are all in the same line, in which case, the second `if` would read the folllowing `<p class="calibre_\d+">` not that one the first `if` is reading?

Comment: No, the second `if` is searching over the same string, so it will see the same match. You'd need to repeat the pattern in the second regex, so it matches only if it's there twice. I prefer the solution posted by @codenheim if you can reorganize the code to work as they suggest.

Comment: I parse it nicely with `Marpa`, much like in the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57069498/4653379). But I don't understand what you want done, can you clarify: Once `p.calibre_[0-9]+` is found, you extract `abc` and ... ? replace the element with it? Add it? Make a link like in the linked post? (I don't see a link in your "_expected_" result).

Comment: @melpomene Looks like it but it's not; it's a custom format (the `</>` needs to stay as it is etc).  There is more about it in (comments to) their previous question, and in the last part of my answer there, linked to in my answer here

Comment: A couple of specific questions to clarify.  (1) By all I can see, the `$entry` and `$hw` in your code are _the same_.  What wouldn't make sense ... am I missing something? (2) You say you want links, and your code prints links, but "_result is expected like this_" doesn't show links?  The code I show in my answer parses the HTML sample completely but i need to know what output you need, so that I can finish that.

Comment: @zdim Sorry to make you confused. (1)Yeah, the `=~` line really shouldn't be there. (2)I just deleted the `<link` part, it's basically irrelevant to put it there, adding to more confusion.

Comment: The expected result is to return a combination of that English word as the first line of each word entry(entry head), the corresponding `<p` tag as the entry body, with the `</>` as the entry tail.

Comment: OK. One more thing.  There is an `A` (another "head"?) there, and a `div` inside of which is the `1. abc` thing, but also another `<p>` before it (which has no english words). The expected results shows all of these gone? What does that mean -- the whole structure that _contains_ a `<p>` with English words is replaced?  (Then what if it contains _two_ (or more) `<p>`'s with English words?)   Or does the "expected result" repalce only that `<p>` that had english words?  Then does that get embedded inside the original `A-div`, or added after it?

Comment: I wouldn't use the word `replace`, it's more of an `extract` thing. That is to extract all `<p` tag (to use as entry body eventually) with certain class containing certain pattern (to use as an entry head eventually) in its content. Everything else is disregarded, be it `div` or other `<p` tags that don't pass the regex match. They're gone because they didn't pass the match.:)

Comment: @jonah_w Alright, that clarifies it.  Edited answer accordingly, to produce needed otuput

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an HTML fragment, so it is better to parse it using a library. However, it is not a fully valid HTML (note that `</>`), what throws off most parsers.

I find that [Marpa::HTML](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/JKEGL/Marpa-HTML-0.112000/lib/Marpa/HTML.pm) can parse even this though. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57069498/4653379), where the question originates.

The requirement is to extract particular elements and form custom-format "*entries*," shown in the question under "*result is expected*," and clarified in comments.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Marpa::HTML qw(html);   
use utf8;    
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $html = <<END_HTML;
A
<div class="notes"><p class="calibre_2"> 注：</p><p class="calibre_2"> 1.abc 字母</p>
<div class="notes"><p class="calibre_1">7. some calibre_1 as well</p>
</>
END_HTML    #/    
say $html;

my @entries_with_Eng;            
my $new_html = Marpa::HTML::html( \$html, {
    'p' => sub {
        my $attr = Marpa::HTML::attributes();
        if (exists $attr->{class} and $attr->{class} =~ /calibre_[0-9]+/) { #/
            my $cont = Marpa::HTML::contents();
            say "contents: $cont";
            if ($cont =~ /[0-9]+\s*\.\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)/) {
                my $entry = "$1\n" . Marpa::HTML::original() . "\n</>";
                push @entries_with_Eng, $entry;
            }
        }
        return;
    },
});

say '';  say for @entries_with_Eng;
```

Note that I extract only a simple-minded selection (ascii `\w`, and with a space too so to also capture all such words); please complete that to what defines "*English words*" for your purpose.

If the HTML string should be changed (and not only some data extracted) that is done by `return`-ing new content from the closure, what changes the processed item and thus the returned `$new_html` string  (reference) then differs from the original.  See module documentation.

The above prints

```
A
<div class="notes"><p class="calibre_2"> 注：</p><p class="calibre_2"> 1.abc  字母</p>
<div class="notes"><p class="calibre_1">7. some calibre_1 as well</p>
</>

contents:  注：
contents:  1.abc  字母
contents: 7. some calibre_1 as well

abc  
<p class="calibre_2"> 1.abc  字母</p>
</>
some calibre_1 as well
<p class="calibre_1">7. some calibre_1 as well</p>
</>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks @zdim. This has been crystal clear.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring whether a regex is going to handle all of your cases, I will just suggest to use the global flag

> /g

for the regex matching and forget about lines.

Pull the whole file into a string from `<DICT>` (use slurp mode by undefining $\), then use a global regex on the string to match. Use strict regex so that your patterns don't match multiples, and just iterate.

http://archive.oreilly.com/oreillyschool/courses/Perl3/Perl3-04.html

A global regex tells Perl regex engine to maintain a bookmark between matches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @codenheim Each `<p class="calibre_\d+">` tag is in one line itself. In this case, do I still need to use the `$\`?

Comment: If so just regex on the string as suggested ignoring the fact that they are 1 line per.. Or use your original code if they are indeed 1 per line, since your problem goes away, no?

Comment: Yeah, it's gone now. Thanks for your alternative solution.