# loop through global substitution and execute code in loop

Tags: regex, perl, while-loop

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

mkdir "images";
$url = "https://www.somedomain.com/";
$mech = new WWW::Mechanize;
$mech->get($url);
$num = 1;
$year = 2019;
$number = 23;

$content = q{<P><div class="row" style="text-align:center"><a target="_blank" href="/image/SG0092a.gif"><img src="/image/SG0092a.gif"  alt="graphic image" class="img-responsive graphic"/></a></div><div class="row" style="text-align:center"><a target="_blank" href="/image/SG0092b.gif"><img src="/image/SG0092b.gif"  alt="graphic image" class="img-responsive graphic"/></a></div><div class="row" style="text-align:center"><a target="_blank" href="/image/SG0092c.gif"><img src="/image/SG0092c.gif"  alt="graphic image" class="img-responsive graphic"/></a></div><div class="row" style="text-align:center"><a target="_blank" href="/image/SG0092d.gif"><img src="/image/SG0092d.gif"  alt="graphic image" class="img-responsive graphic"/></a></div><div class="row" style="text-align:center"><a target="_blank" href="/image/SG0092e.gif"><img src="/image/SG0092e.gif"  alt="graphic image" class="img-responsive graphic"/></a></div>};

while ($content =~ s/(<img.+?src=)"([^>]+?)\.([A-Za-z]+)"/$1"images\/${year}_${number}_$num.$3"/g)
{
    $imageuri = "$2.$3";
    print $imageuri, "\n";
    $mech->get($imageuri);
    $mech->save_content("images/${year}_${number}_$num.$3");
    $num++;
}

print $content, "\n";
```

Is it possible to do the above in perl?  I would like the `src` attributes of the `img` elements replaced with a new path and filename and for the image files to be downloaded and saved with that path and filename.

Comment: `while ($content =~ s/pattern/repl/g)` should be `while ($content =~ /pattern/g)`

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: @ikegami I need the substitution to take place

Comment: Do the substitution afterwards, or use the approach I described in answer to your earlier question to do both at once. Or use a proper HTML parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following (but you should really consider using a real HTML parser):

```
$content =~ s{(<img.+?src=)"([^>]+?)\.([A-Za-z]+)"}{
    my $imageuri = "$2.$3";
    print $imageuri, "\n";
    $mech->get($imageuri);
    my $file = "images/${year}_${number}_$num.$3";
    $num++;
    $mech->save_content($file);
    qq($1"$file")
}eg;
```

The `e` modifier on the substitution operator makes perl parse the replacement part as a block of code, not a string.

---

Other notes:

- Always start your Perl files with `use strict; use warnings;` or equivalent (e.g. `use strict` can be replaced by `use v5.12.0` or higher).
- Avoid indirect object syntax (`new WWW::Mechanize`). Use normal method calls instead (`WWW::Mechanize->new`).
- Use local variables (e.g. `my $num = 1;`) unless you really need package variables.

Comment: What is the problem in using "indirect object syntax" to create an object?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it with an HTML parser, [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder).

This changes the `src` attribute to the new value in the processed node and replaces that node in the tree with the changed copy, for all `img` tags.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $content = join '', <DATA>;  # join in general (not needed with one line)

my ($num, $year, $number) = (1, 2019, 23);
my $new_src_base = "images/${year}_${number}_$num";

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($content);

my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'img');

for my $node (@nodes) {
    my ($ext) =  $node->attr('src') =~ m{.*/.*\.(.*)\z};    #/
    my $orig_src = $node->attr('src', $new_src_base . ".$ext");  # change 'src'
    $node->replace_with($node);
    # my $imageurl = $orig_src;  # fetch the image etc...
    # $mech->get($imageurl);             
}

say $tree->as_HTML;   # to inspect; otherwise print to file

__DATA__
<P><div class="row" style="text-align:center"><a target="_blank" href="/image/SG0092a.gif"> <img src="/image/SG0092a.gif"  alt="graphic image" class="img-responsive graphic"/></a></div> <div class="row" style="text-align:center"><a target="_blank" href="/image/SG0092b.gif"> <img src="/image/SG0092b.gif"  alt="graphic image" class="img-responsive graphic"/></a></div> <div class="row" style="text-align:center"><a target="_blank" href="/image/SG0092c.gif"> <img src="/image/SG0092c.gif"  alt="graphic image" class="img-responsive graphic"/></a></div> <div class="row" style="text-align:center"><a target="_blank" href="/image/SG0092d.gif"> <img src="/image/SG0092d.gif"  alt="graphic image" class="img-responsive graphic"/></a></div> <div class="row" style="text-align:center"><a target="_blank" href="/image/SG0092e.gif"> <img src="/image/SG0092e.gif"  alt="graphic image" class="img-responsive graphic"/></a></div>
```

For the new name of `src` attribute I copy what I can infer from the OP.  The code in the question leaves `href` attribute of the link unchanged (path to the same gif) so this code leaves that, too.

There are other tools to do this with, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57069498/4653379) for more, for example.

---

The above could perhaps run into problems related to *weak references* in older versions, see documentation. Then this should be safer

```
for my $node (@nodes) {
    my ($ext) =  ( $node->attr('src') ) =~ m{.*/.*\.(.*)\z};  #/
    my $copy = $node->clone;
    my $orig_src = $copy->attr('src', $new_src_base . ".$ext");
    $node->replace_with($copy)->delete;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($content);
my $num = 1;
foreach my $img ($dom->find('img[src]')->each) {
  next unless $img->{src} =~ m/\.([a-zA-Z]+)\z/;
  my $ext = $1;
  my $path = "images/${year}_${number}_$num.$ext";
  $ua->get($img->{src})->result->save_to($path);
  $img->attr(src => $path);
  $num++;
}

print $dom->to_string;
```